# Would a company take a game pitch seriously if they were pitched a fully finished game?

Tags: business

Let's say hypothetically that I had a fully realized and functioning game using a well known IP (a character from Nintendo or from another company, for instance), where the game is finished and wouldn't have any development time, would they entertain the idea to release it?

It would be made with their characters so I would have no right to it (in the case of money) but would they entertain the idea if they found it good and fresh.?

I have seen answers to this question saying a definite *no* for they were presented an idea of a game and not a completed product. And I know most people would want compensation for there time, but if it's already done and bug tested, play tested and polished, would they entertain the idea if they found they wouldn't have much to do on their end and I would not seek any rights to the design?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most of the same legal entanglements exist for trying to pitch finished projects as exist for trying to pitch "ideas." So your chances here are slim.

A game *development* company likely wouldn't be interested at all, simply because they are not in the business of publishing finished games... that's what a publisher is for. Unless the company is fully-independent, it's very likely they couldn't make the decision anyway, since they don't usually own the intellectual property.

A game *publishing* company might, since that's more in line with what they actually do. However, most of them are unlikely to entertain solicitation from unknown developers, and many of them are unlikely to be pleased with the fact that something was built using their intellectual property without permission. IP owners tend to have plans for their IP themselves, and don't need you to take it off in some random direction they don't want.

It also extremely unlikely, for the same reason, that they would consider this game "finished" even if you do: they may want their own modifications to support their future IP plans, or plans to push certain technologies they may be invested in, et cetera.

If you want to pitch an idea for a game based on a publisher's IP to a publisher successfully, you probably:

- want to come at it without a "finished" product; something far along is fine, but if you present it as something that needs no additional work and thus has no opportunity for their input on their own IP you'll likely just get a cease-and-desist order.
- don't actually want to *incorporate* their intellectual property in your pitch prototypes. Use placeholders and explain in the pitch itself that you'd like it to leverage whatever IP. This demonstrates respect for their property that you don't necessarily show when you just use it without asking and them come to them afterwards.
- want to have a portfolio of games you've shipped already, or be part of a company that has developed games that sold already (and speaking officially on behalf of that company) so that somebody will actually give you the time of day in the first place.

Comment: "The one exception is when you have some demonstrated expertise that would give you something unique and compelling to offer the IP holder, something you can do for them that's outside of their experience - as arguably Niantic brought to the table with their mobile, location-based gaming know-how (and geomapping data) from Ingress."

Comment: Ok this linked helped... I would say a project would be malable enough for the Publisher could change it to their liking and direction. I would say not so much as pitch the idea as lay it at there feet and say if you like this please make use of it!!. Otherwise lock it away or do what you want with it for otherwise i have no use for it. kind of deal. No intention on keeping it, but would probabaly use it in a portfolio (replacing the IP of course) to show my skills.  Im like obsessed with simple flawless mechanics and a hobby project that turned out more fun that any game recently released.